# Discord.js, how to handle error sending private message to user with disabled privacy setting and return right after error?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, return, try-catch

Is there possible way to handle error that will return right back after error is triggered?

```
  if(command === 'test') {
    message.author.send('Dm Test').catch(error => {
      message.reply('I failed to send you a private message!')
      return;
    })
    //some code below, should not trigger after sending message error.
```

The problem is that `.catch` will respond as last, how to handle this error and immediately return instead of running also code below? I tried to use `try {` but that didn't work.

```
message.author.send('') 
   .catch(() => message.reply("Can't send DM to your user!"));
```

Would like to know if there is another way to handle error. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `.catch()` executes after the rest of your code is because `.send()` is asynchronous and returns a `Promise`. Think of it this way: each time you send a message, discord.js has to send an HTTP request to the Discord API, wait for a response, and then give you the data from the response. That process is not instantaneous and takes some time, which is why using the `Promise` structure is very useful.

As for the specific problem, you simply want to await the response of your `.catch()`. This can be done by making the function you are running this code in `async`. Here is an example:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {

    let response = await message.author.send('').catch(() => {
        message.reply("Can't send DM to your user!"));
        return false;
    });

    // (If error occurred, 'response' will be false)
    if (!response) return; // Return if the error occurred

    // ... Code for if error did not occur
    // (If no error occurred, 'response' will contain sent message)

});
```

The `await` keyword will wait until the asynchronous line you are executing has been fulfilled (i.e. until the return value has been obtained or an error has been caught) before continuing on with your code. Note the use of the `async` keyword. You can only use `await` within functions marked `async`.

Comment: Thank you! I feel dumb that I didn't come up with this, as my command is in the async function itself, so I easily added let response and response statement below in my already made async function. Works like a charm! All kudos to you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you place a `return` before sending the error message, JavaScript will read that as you're returning the message so if you do the following:

```js
message.author.send('') 
   .catch(() => return message.reply("Can't send DM to your user!"));
```

you'll have the error message be the final command run and nothing else will follow.

Comment: Hello, I already tried this and in way you sent it's not correct format.

```message.author.send('') 
   .catch(() => { return message.reply("Can't send DM to your user!");
  })```

Even this, the problem is that .catch is ran as last... so the return will happen after whole code is executed...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try` inside of `if & else` statement to know if you can dm the person or not.

```
if(command === 'test') {
   try {
     message.author.send("Something right here")
   } catch {
     message.channel.send("I can't dm this person.")
   } else {
    //something exploration code here
   }
}
```